Can you add and/or multiply splines as new splines in SciPy?
I am using Scipy to construct cubic splines, and I need to add and multiply the outputs of the CubicSpline objects. I am wondering whether it is possible to create new splines that give the added and multiplied outputs from the old CubicSpline objects.
Now, I defined new functions f,g that add and multiply the respective output, but this prevents me from using useful methods of the piecewise polynomial like roots, derivative and integrate. Is there a way to combine these splines to create new splines that retain the methods. Perhaps by adding/multiplying the polynomial coefficients? Would this only be possible when the splines use the same breakpoints x1 == x2 or also when they differ?
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline  

spline1 = CubicSpline(x1, y1) 
spline2 = CubicSpline(x2, y2)  

def f(x):     
    return spline1(x) + spline2(x)

def g(x):
     return spline1(x) * spline2(x)


The parent class PPoly has an extend method.

Not directly.
If your x arrays are the same, you can manipulate the the coefficient arrays, spline1.c, and construct a new PPoly object with the new coefficients.
If their x arrays differ, your best bet is to resample the splines on the same grid and manipulate the coefficients.
